# What is the correct method to delete a variation subsite (label) in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: support

What is the correct method to delete a variation subsite (label) in SharePoint 2010?
Is just deleting the label from the variation labels page and then deleting the sub web enough?
What will happen to the relationships list?